# Understanding install OpenPGP on Debian

Tags: debian, php, gnome-keyring

I have Debian Buster on VirtualBox, I install these **open keyrings** because I will install **PHP**.

```
https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

I doing

`#apt update`

`#apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https lsb-release curl unzip -y`

Now install OpenPGP Key distribution, how Debian to [tell](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#OpenPGP_Key_distribution),

```
wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/apt.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

then doing

`#apt update`

`#apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3`

`#apt install apache2 -y`

`#apt install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-curl php7.3-gd php7.3-intl php7.3-json  php7.3-mbstring php7.3-mysql php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline php7.3-xml php7.3-xsl php7.3-zip php7.3-bz2 libapache2-mod-php7.3 -y`

**PHP** and **Apache** is installed and all working gut, my question is, I to need to add a **signed** File to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt.gpg` how Debian tell [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Sources.list_entry) for later Update it, I trying to do it with `nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` and add these Line on it,

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/apt.gpg]  https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/buster/Release
```

but when give `apt update`, come a warning that to say which my sources.list can't all Download.

Can Please someone answer me on this question, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question;

> I to need to add a **signed** File to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt.gpg as Debian [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Sources.list_entry) to say.

I found the solution on how to does it..

I to do how https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt to say

> ${SUDO} apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
>
> ${SUDO} wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
>
> ${SUDO} sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
>
> ${SUDO} apt-get update

With this command create the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` File and add the **keyrings** to **sources.list.d** as Debian [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Sources.list_entry) to say.

```
# sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/apt.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
```